# Make this preg_replace do the opposite

Tags: php, preg-replace

This preg_replace detects digits (ie 123456789 or (234) 345-6789 or 123 777 3233, etc)  between double `""` single `''` and forward slashes `//` and ignores all other digits in the text:

`$text = preg_replace_callback('/(("[^"]|\'[^\']|\/[^\/])\+?[\d-\(\)\s]{8,25}[0-9]?\d)/', '$1', $text);`

I want the opposite. I want it to IGNORE digits between double `""` single `''` and forward slashes `//` and find all other digits in the text. What should be done to accomplish that?

** Thanks to whoever suggested one of the solutions on SO. Here it is:

`$text = preg_replace('/".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\'.*?\'(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\/.*?\/(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b(\+?[\d-\(\)\s]{8,25}[0-9]?\d\b)/s', '$1', $text);`

Comment: not my vote, but you keep asking and then deleting even after people have tried to help you, kind of annoying that.

Comment: [Repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57368196/preg-match-numbers-between-8-and-25-digits-except-between-double-quotes-single) from yesterday? // Either `\K` or `(*SKIP)`, or the alternative approach: strip away quoted strings from input firstly, then apply the number-extraction part. (Unclear if that's the real task).

Comment: oh not deleting, multiple user names, my apologies.